# PHP class autoloading when creating class dynamically?

Tags: php, reflection, autoload

This simple example won't work, gives me:

> Fatal error: spl_autoload() [function.spl-autoload]: Class GmailServer
>   could not be loaded.

```
define('USERNAME', 'username');
define('PASSWORD', 'password');
$SERVER = 'GmailServer';

spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
spl_autoload_register();

use Service\Mail\GmailServer;

$server = new $SERVER(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

While, of course, this is working:

```
$server = new GmailServer(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

Am i'm missing something?

**EDIT**: Working with reflection (but you HAVE to specify the full namespace):

```
$reflector = new \ReflectionClass("Service\\Mail\\$SERVER");
$server = $reflector->newInstance(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
```

Comment: Are you sure `GmailServer.php` exists in the current folder?

Comment: Yes, and also `new GmailServer` one line below will work.

Comment: It may be a namespace bug.... have you tried with the qualified class name, or moving GmailServer into a Service/Mail folder? Alternatively, [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) might help - with __construct as the function name

Comment: @PhilLello `GmailServer` is already in `Service/Mail` folder, thanks for helping.

Comment: I second Phil Lello, I think it's namespace related. When he said "fully qualified name", he meant `$SERVER = 'Service\Mail\GmailServer';`

Comment: @Savageman is this a bug or a wanted behavior?

Comment: @Gremo Only the gods of PHP can answer that. I'd lean towards bug - remember PHP class and namespaces were added quite late.

Comment: @Phil Lello I've just noticed that running the script through CLI gives me errors about missing classes - again - because of namespaces, even with reflector! Sadly switching to to the old `require`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to run this?

```
class Foo { }
$c = "Foo";
$f = new $c();
```

If it does, it might be namespace related. If not, and also, I'd rather do that than using this quirk, use a factory pattern:

```
static class ServerFactory 
{
    public static function GetServer($server, $username, $password)
    {
         switch ($server)
        {
            case "GmailServer": return new GmailServer($username, $password);   
        }      
    } 
}
```

Comment: Of course your first example would work because the lack of namespace. I will use reflection class, but the question is still why it's not working when namespace is defined. Is this a bug?

Comment: +1 because I like using factories whenever possible - it makes it _so_ much easier to change implementations in one place.